# How can I avoid table print without line in the footer?

Tags: html, css

Actually I'm working in a report that doesn't has border bottom and top

this is the css

```
.table tbody tr td {
                            padding: 1px;
                            color: #000000;
                            background-color: #FFFFFF;
                            border-top: 0px solid #FFFFFF !important;
                            border-bottom: 0px solid #FFFFFF !important;
                            border-left: 1px solid #000000 !important;
                            border-right: 1px solid #000000 !important;
                        }
```

And the code is this

```
<tbody>

                                <div t-foreach="o.get_print_lines_media_carta_led(o)" t-as="d" width="100%">
                                    <t t-if="d['code'] != 'ls'">

                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width:5%;text-align:left;padding-left: 0.9em !important;" class='letra2'>
                                                <t t-esc="d['code']" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:20%; text-align:left;padding-left: 0.9em !important;" class='letra2'>
                                                <t t-esc="d['code_name']" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:25%; text-align:left;padding-left: 0.9em !important;" class='letra2'>
                                                <t t-esc="d['name']"/>  
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:10%; text-align:right;padding-right: 0.9em !important;" class='letra2'>
                                                <t t-esc="'{:,.2f}'.format(d['debit'])" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:10%; text-align:right;padding-right: 0.9em !important;" class='letra2'>
                                                <span t-esc="'{:,.2f}'.format(d['credit'])"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </t>
                               </div>
                          </tbody>
```

I need that the end of every page has a end line like the next photo
[image]

Comment: Please read _[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_.

Comment: Hi! you have defined 'border-top: 0px' and 'border-bottom: 0px', that's why you don't get a bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you have your borders on top and bottom 0px. You should change that in the css.